# Process StandardOutput ReadToEnd get null/empty string when multiple processes

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, redirectstandardoutput

I try to use `Parallel.For` to run process and get output parallelly.

Sample code like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        Parallel.For(0, int.MaxValue, i =>
        {
            bag.Add(MyMethod());
        });
    }

    public static string MyMethod()
    {
        using (var a = new Process())
        {
            a.StartInfo.FileName = "A.exe";
            a.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            a.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            a.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            a.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            a.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            a.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            a.Start();
            string output = a.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            a.WaitForExit();
            return output; // sometime output will be null
        }
    }
}
```

A.exe code

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("A");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why output will null and how could I avoid get null result?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to figure out why get null in stream.

If I add `Thread.Sleep()` before A.exe output, main process's `ReadToEnd()` will wait for A.exe output and get result.

Only one situation will cause null stream is the A.exe exit and no output.

This will let `ReadToEnd()` get null and `Peek()` didn't help because A.exe is exit and no longer output anymore.

I think my problem is my program is running at a heavy loading Windows Server 2003 R2 32bit, `Process.Start()` didn't get exception when the process can't start. It cause no output to stream, the process exit and stream close.

Comment: Did you try out the `a.SystemError` stream?